# Cannot access global array in main after initializing in another function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm having a hard time understanding why I cannot access my global 2D array in my main function after I have initialized it already in another function. 
EDIT: Forgot to specify that `d` is a known int variable declared before all of this, usually 3 or 4.

```
void init();

int **board;

int main(){
    init();
    cout << board[0][0];
}

void init(){
    int **board = new int*[d];
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        board[i] = new int[d];
        }

    int n=d*d;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            board[i][j] = n;
            n--;
        }
    }
```

So the moment I try to access `board[0][0]` in `main()` I get an "Access violation at 0x00000000".
 I enter debugging and see that `board[0][0]` points to `0x000000` when being called in `main()` but if I try to call it in the `init()` function, at the end for example, it works perfectly and I can access any variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void init(){
    int **board = new int*[d];
```

Here, you are defining a **local** variable `board` in the function which blocks the **global** variable `board`.

Instead, assign the value directly, don't define another variable:

```
void init(){
    board = new int*[d];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. This small newbie mistake that was hiding in plain sight was annoying me for about 2 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new temporary variable:

```
int **board = new int*[d];
```

This is a **memory leak** and you cannot access the memory after the function. You can just do this:

```
board = new int*[d]; //remember to delete []!
```

I see you have tagged your question [c++]. If this is the case, you should be using the standard library instead of dealing with raw pointers. `std::vector` and `std::array` come to mind.

Comment: Thank you. Your and Yu Hao's answer brought up some other pointer errors in the full code that I haven't spotted. I initially tagged it as a C question as well, don't know why that isn't showing up. EDIT: I'm using raw pointers instead of the standard library since I'm trying to improve my skills on pointers.

Comment: C does not have `new` so this should not be a C question.